# Can't access vector class members

Tags: c++, vector, std, dev-c++

I have this code:

WItem.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef struct iteminfo {
int rowid;
   char* item;
   int type;
   int extra;
   int objectid;
} item;


class CItem {
 public:
    void push(int rowid, char* item, int type, int extra, int objectid);
    std::vector<iteminfo> data;
};
```

WItem.cpp

```
#include "witem.h"

void CItem::push(int rowid, char* item, int type, int extra, int objectid) {
   iteminfo* temp = new iteminfo;
   temp->rowid = rowid;
   temp->item = item;
   temp->type = type;
   temp->extra = extra;
   temp->objectid = objectid;

   this.data.push_back(temp);
}
```

And I get these errors:

- `data' is not a type
- request for member of non-aggregate type before '.' token

And I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Don't `typedef` classes in C++.

Comment: Perhaps you need to indent the code a bit more...

Comment: If the struct is also going to be used in C then typedef is fine, as is using a char* albeit you must be careful with "rule of 3" (which you can't overload in the struct if it's going to be used in C too). (Assuming this isn't the real code and it's really in a separate header with no C++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `this.data` is wrong, needs to be either just `data` or `this->data`
2. `data` is a vector of `iteminfo` and `temp` is `iteminfo *` i.e. a pointer. You don't need to use `new` here, you should just create the item "on the stack" and then use `push_back` to insert a copy of it into your vector.
3. As this is likely to not be C at all, there is no need for the typedef but even more so use `std::string` for strings not `char *`. You are going to get into a lot of mess maintaining these pointers.
4. Preferably do not use `item` both as a type and a member. It's legal but will get confusing in your code.
5. Ideally make `data` a private member of `CItem` (Incidentally if you are using the class names `item` and `CItem` just to reproduce your problem here that's fine but in real code they are poor class names, choose something more descriptive).

Comment: If the OP's code paid money per error, it would be a real cash cow. BDMCH

Comment: That's great, but I'm still using this class under an interface that is accessed by an virtual machine.  A little question: I'm not really using iteminfo as the template of the vector. Instead of this, I'm using a null pointer and I will probably cast this memory address. Is there any big mistake I'm doing with this?

Comment: I think you mean a void * not a null pointer? I would say you probably do not want to try to optimise vector but you can instantiate your template if your aim is to generate less code.

Answer (score 4):

`this.data` should be `this->data`, because `this` is a pointer in C++.

Comment: just one of his errors. There is one other clear error in his code, and other things he's just doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CashCow did a good analysis on the errors. additionally I'd like to point out

- push should take a type `iteminfo`, the parameter list is messy
- `iteminfo` should have a constructor

  `iteminfo(int rowid, char* item, int type, int extra, int objectid);`

  also think of making the members private to protect them against global abuse

if your code example is complete you recognize that class `CItem` is obsolete and may be replaced by `std::vector<iteminfo>` (or a typedef)